# Maths Commons in Java for calculus

Tags: java, math, calculus

I was using Maths commons to solve some matrices and complex numbers
but i now want to integrate and differentiate all types of functions 
but reading [Polynomials section](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html#a4.6_Polynomials)

I cant really make out what to do. I need some help
on **how to make polynomials or other functions with this library and how to differentiate/ integrate it**. 
Thanks for your support.

Comment: What you mean under "differentiate/ integrate"? You can calculate tan or exp using java.lang.Math. So, you want implement these functions yourself? Or collect all of them to one library?

Comment: The whole idea is to interpret a string of a function into the structutures provided in the library and then differentiate or integrate or if possible calculate limits....  i will interpret it into the structure but how will i defferentiate logx or lnx or a^x using these structures they only provide constructors that take coefficients ..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should use [PolynomialFunction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialFunction.html) class to make your polynomials, and then use its methods to differentiate it.

There are [exmples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.commons.math.analysis.polynomials.PolynomialFunction).

Comment: it seems only polynomial not trigonometry or exponents are supported so any other method in which all the functions are supported

Comment: Can u plz help me just give me some examples how will u differentiate 1/x cosx and a^x

Answer (score 0):

I would create your own class for the rules of differentiation and integration. Such as the Product or Quotient rules in differentiation, and create an order of preference for when the rule is carried out.

Break up the polynomial every time there is a + or - sign. This will ensure that each part of the polynomial is differentiated properly. I would do this by placing the parts of the polynomial into an array. After this is done, you can differentiate or integrate the polynomial, then afterwards concatenate it together.

### Rules to look out for

Differentiation: product, quotient, trig (i'm sure you can use java.lang.math for this), blob rule such as (x^2+2x+1)^2, etc.
Integration: Look different ways to integrate, such as integration by parts

These definitely are not all the rules, but every time you think of one, add it to your class.

Comment: Hey thanks for that but i dont have time to create classes , i just want any library that is helpful in this stuff.         But if thats the only thing i can do then  i will do it eventually.